# How to avoid ADFS sign in page?

Tags: adfs2.0, sts-securitytokenservice, loginview

Is there any chance to avoid ADFS sign in window shown in picture below? I have configured custom STS as claim provider trust on ADFS so I have now two options here. Is there a way to automatically set default value here and skip this page?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to note that this isn't the login page - it is the Home Realm Discovery (HRD) page.

If you have:

```
<persistIdentityProviderInformation enabled="true" lifetimeInDays="30" />
```

set in your web.config, it will only ask you once and then remember your selection for the "lifetimeInDays" number of days.

You can alter the HRD page - there are many references to this e.g.

[Customizing Client Logon and Home Realm Discovery Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb625464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[ADFS 2.0 Home Realm Discovery Deluxe](http://www.idmcrisis.com/post/2011/11/03/ADFS-20-Home-Realm-Discovery-Deluxe.aspx) 
[Home Realm Discovery In WIF And ADFS 2.0 By Query String](http://blog.torresdal.net/2010/04/19/home-realm-discovery-in-wif-and-adfs-2-0-by-query-string/)

Comment: Where can the web.config file be found?

Comment: In IIS under adfs/ls.